# How to apply a function to multiple FASTA sequences within a text file?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I have multiple fasta sequences within a text file, looking like this:

```
>header1
ACTGACTG
>header2
ATGCATGC
...
```

I would like to apply a function all of the sequences at once. Is there a function achieving this?

Every answer will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for parallel computing there are R packages like `parallel` that can help. But the question is too braod to be answerable as it is, please edit giving more details.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on using GNU parallel in bioinformatics: https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/7af2ab5e88ef238da2d9f36b4be203c0
(this site is for programming-related questions; https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ is probably what you want in future)

Comment: See if this package helps - [seqinr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=seqinr). Clarify what is the expected output - "apply a function" - is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple =  `sapply()`. If you want to apply function e.g. to a list of some objects, you use `sapply()` method, which is a `map()` function (you may know this from python). Here is an example:

```
v <- sample(1:100, 10)
> v
 [1] 92 69 87 42  7 33 51 62 26 80
f <- function(x){
+     # T if even else F
+     return(!x %% 2)
+ }
> sapply(v, FUN = f)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Example with DNA:

```
> library('dplyr')
> v <- c('ATGCTAGCT', 'GTGTACGTAC')
> sapply(v, FUN = function(dna){
+     return(dna %>% tolower)
+ })
   ATGCTAGCT   GTGTACGTAC 
 "atgctagct" "gtgtacgtac"
```